# how to separate an sql query into chain methods

Tags: php, oop

I am new in oop and I am trying to change a sql query into 3 chained method and use like this:
$mtag = $mtag->allTags()->orderBy()->lastThree();

```
public function allTags()
{
    $sql = "SELECT tag_id FROM posts_tags ";
    $sql .= "GROUP BY tag_id ";
    $sql .= "ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3 ";
    $res = self::builder($sql);
    return $res;
}
```

i want to use each $sql in to a separate chain method .
how can i do this?
i have tried this but it doesnt work

```
public function allTags()
{
    $sql = "SELECT tag_id FROM posts_tags ";
    self::builder($sql);
    return $this;
}

public function orderBy()
{
    $sql = "GROUP BY tag_id ";
    self::builder($sql);
    return $this;
}

public function lastThree()
{
    $sql = "ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3 ";
    self::builder($sql);
    return $this;
}
```

my builder method looks like this

```
public function builder(string $sql)
{
    $stmt = $this->database->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    if (!$stmt) {
        throw new Exception("Query failed . . .");
    }
    return $stmt;
}
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how you call your chained methods, and what SQL they produce? When you say, "It doesn't work"...what happens instead?

Comment: @DavidHempy $mtag = $mtag->allTags()->orderBy()->lastThree();

Comment: you can't prepare a statement in little pieces - it should be the entire sql statement that gets evaluated in the call to `prepare` it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `self::builder($sql);` method directly prepares the sql statement, instead of waiting for it to be completely constructed:

```
$mtag = $mtag
    /*
    the first self::builder($sql) is called,
    prepares the statement without the order and group by
    */
    ->allTags()
    /*
    the second self::builder($sql) is called from orderBy, prepares "GROUP BY tag_id "
    probably a syntax error is hidden here
    */
    ->orderBy()
    /*
    the third self::builder($sql) is called from lastThree
    it tries to prepare "ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3 "
    a syntax error is probably hidden here too
    */
    ->lastThree();
```

The statement is prepared over and over again. You can avoid this by doing, in that order

1. defining the statement with all its chained variants
2. calling a method to fetch data, preparing the statement composed from the various chained method calls.

```
$stmt = $mtag->allTags()->orderBy()->lastThree();
$result = $stmt->resolve();
```

where `$stmt = $this->database->prepare($sql);` only happens in the resolve method.

Answer (score -1):

you have error in return code.

Change to that code!

```
public function lastThree()
{
    $sql = "ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 3 ";
    $res = self::builder($sql);
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: not sure that will work as we do not know what the `builder` method does. It would need to be the same for the other methods too if you are correct